# Removing item from Dictionary in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, foreach

I have something like this:

```
    Public Shared Property PinnedChannelConnectionIds() As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of String))
    Get
        If _pinnedChannelConnectionIds Is Nothing Then
            Return New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of String))
        Else
            Return _pinnedChannelConnectionIds
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of String)))
        _pinnedChannelConnectionIds = value
    End Set
End Property
```

And then, have some data in dictionary as :

1, {"c1","c2", "c3"} 
2, {"c2","c4", "c6"} 
3, {"c3","c5", "c1"} 
4, {"c4","c3", "c6"}

So to remove a specific item. Let say "c2" from the above dictionary.
I am doing like this:

```
For Each channelKeyValuePair As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, List(Of String)) In Channel.PinnedChannelConnectionIds
            For Each item As String In channelKeyValuePair.Value.ToList()
                If (item.Equals("c2")) Then
                    Channel.PinnedChannelConnectionIds(channelKeyValuePair.Key).Remove(item)
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

But it throws error : **Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they cannot be used to modify the underlying collection.**

Can anyone please help me out.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The code that you've shown does not produce any error, it works okay. supply real code sample that can reproduce the error. Are you using an IEnumerable?, just do a copy of your collection without the item that you want to delete. see remarks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That code looks like it is *preserving* "c2" and deleting the rest rather than the reverse.  No need for `ToList` or even to iterate the list, just use `If kvp.Value.Contains("c2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest something like

```
For Each channelKeyValuePair As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, List(Of String)) In Channel.PinnedChannelConnectionIds
    channelKeyValuePair.Value.RemoveAll(Function(x) x = "C2")
Next
```

might work. There's no need to iterate over the list elements to find and remove them and it can cause difficulties of the sort you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BrianHooper